# update Jenkins security settings

Tags: jenkins

I update Jenkins security settings to support allure report

```
System.setProperty(“hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

it works fine ,now I need to add

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts;")
```

for HTML report

how can I combine both settings into 1 ?

Thanks , Mor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this one

**System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; frame-src 'self';")**

do the trick